# Problema ao receber valores char

Tags: c#, console

Porque a primeira vez que passo um valor char da erro (como se fosse vazio)? Depois na segunda tentativa funciona normal?

> Após eu receber a **inicial do Cargo ou Turno** da erro e mesmo assim dei
>   um *WriteLine* estava com o valor correto, sendo necessário digitar de
>   novo.

```
/**
 * 5) Uma empresa possui dez funcionários com as seguintes características: 
 * código, número de horas trabalhadas no mês, 
 * turno de trabalho(M - Matutino, V - Vespertino ou N - Noturno), 
 * categoria (O - Operário ou G - Gerente), 
 * valor da hora trabalhada. 
 * Sabendo-se que esta empresa deseja informatizar a folha de pagamento, faça um programa que:
 * a) Leia as informações do funcionário, não permitindo que sejam informados turnos ou categorias
 * inexistentes. Trabalhar sempre com a digitação de letras maiúsculas.
 * 
 * Calcule o valor da hora trabalhada, conforme tabela a seguir: -- slide ---
 * 
 * Adote o valor de R$150,00 para o salário mínimo.
 * c) Calcule o salário inicial dos funcionários com base no valor da hora trabalhada e 
 * o número de horas trabalhadas.
 * d) Calcule o valor do auxílio alimentação recebido por funcionário, 
 * de acordo com o seu salário inicial, conforme tabela a seguir: --- slide -- **/


int codigo, controle = 1;
double h_trabalhadas, valor_h_trabalho;
char turno, categoria;
string aux;

while(controle <= 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("Código do funcionário: ");
    aux = Console.ReadLine();
    codigo = Convert.ToInt16(aux);

    Console.WriteLine("Número de horas trabalhadas por mês: ");
    aux = Console.ReadLine();
    h_trabalhadas = Convert.ToDouble(aux);

    Console.WriteLine("Turno (M/V/N): ");
    aux = Console.ReadLine();
    turno = Convert.ToChar(aux);


    //Validar turno
    while((turno != 'M')||(turno != 'V')||(turno != 'N'))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Turno inválido, tente novamente");
        Console.WriteLine("Turno (M/V/N): ");
        aux = Console.ReadLine();
        turno = Convert.ToChar(aux);

        if ((turno == 'M') || (turno == 'V') || (turno == 'N'))
            break;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Categoria (O/P): ");
    aux = Console.ReadLine();
    categoria = Convert.ToChar(aux);

    //Validar categoria
    while ((categoria != 'O') || (categoria != 'P'))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Categoria inválida, tente novamente");
        Console.WriteLine("Categoria (O/P): ");
        aux = Console.ReadLine();
        categoria = Convert.ToChar(aux);

        if ((categoria == 'O') || (categoria == 'P'))
            break;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Valor da hora de trabalho: ");
    aux = Console.ReadLine();
    valor_h_trabalho = Convert.ToDouble(aux);
```

Testar código: https://repl.it/K859

Desta forma, se eu digitei 'M' porque solicitou de novo..

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual seria o erro que está ocorrendo ?

Comment: Não aparece erro só que quando eu entro com o valor: M para o turno ele solicita pra eu digitar de novo, como se não tivesse reconhecido o caractere ai entra no while(), coloquei o site pra testar ai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `while` que valida esta entrada deveria estar usando `&&` e não `||`.

Ou seja:

> Se o valor digitado for diferente de M **e também diferente** de V e **também diferente de** N.

```
while((turno != 'M') && (turno != 'V') && (turno != 'N'))
```

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/n0f67O)

Comment: Compreendi, obrigado novamente amigo!

Answer (score 1):

A lógica de seus WHILE é o problema.

> A instrução while executa uma instrução ou um bloco de instruções até
>   que uma expressão especificada seja avaliada como false.

Referência: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/while

Por exemplo, se eu digitar um M, o seu while ficara como:

```
while(false||true||true)
```

que é o mesmo que:

```
while(true)
```

O mesmo ira acontecer com qualquer um dos outros dois valores se eles forem escolhidos. Agora note que, independente do valor inserido, sempre haverá duas expressões do seu WHILE iguais a verdadeiro, isso é suficiente para que o seu WHILE sempre seja executado, independente do valor inserido ser correto.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta mano, só faltou mesmo ter informado como eu arrumava isso